# JavaMail POP3 Office AuthenticationFailedException: Logon failure: unknown user name and bad password

Tags: java, spring, outlook, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to read microsoft office emails with basic authentication (email and password), but I can't log in, the error says that email or password are wrong, but I tried them and they are correct.

**FailedException**:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

**Setting**:

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", "outlook.office365.com");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", 995);
            if ("pop3s".equals(prop.getMailStoreType())) {
                properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            }
            else {
                properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "false");               
            }
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            emailSession.setDebug(true);
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect("outlook.office365.com", prop.getUsername(), prop.getPassword());
```

Here it goes into an exception.

**Debug JavaMail Logging**:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.enable: true
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.finalizecleanclose: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "outlook.office365.com", port 995, isSSL true
+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready. [WgBSADAAUAAyADcAOABDAEEAMAAwADQAOQAuAEMASABFAFAAMgA3ADgALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
CAPA
+OK
TOP
UIDL
SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2
USER
.
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command failed
QUIT
+OK Microsoft Exchange Server POP3 server signing off.
```